# Unity Editor - Adding Object Fields on button click

Tags: unity

So I am trying to make a button that will spawn an object field and a float field when clicked. Each object field being unique, so I can add gameobjects to it. I can’t think of a way to do this. This is purely Editor Scripting. Also, if there is an option to delete a row (the object field and the FloatField) that would be amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some quick code I wrote down. Hope this solves the issue you were having.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class SomethingEditor : EditorWindow {

    private static List<Object> objs = new List<Object>();
    private static List<float> floats = new List<float>();
    private static Vector2 v = Vector2.zero;

    [MenuItem("MenuItem/Test")]
    private static void DoIt () { EditorWindow.GetWindow<SomethingEditor>(); }

    void OnGUI () {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(v);

        if(GUILayout.Button("Create an object")) {
            floats.Add(default(float));
            objs.Add(default(Object));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < objs.Count; i++) {
            objs[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(objs[i], typeof(Object), false);
            floats[i] = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(floats[i]);
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Print")) {
            for (var i = 0; i < objs.Count; i++) {
                Debug.Log(objs[i]);
                Debug.Log(floats[i]);
            }
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
}
```

You can obviously make changes to make the editor look better, but you can have something like this.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do the remove part?

Comment: You can remove the last item from the list, or you can pass a specific index, and you can remove the entry at that index. It would be similar code as the first `if` clause